# How to parallelize a table of contour plots

Tags: plotting, parallelization

I have this simple code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[-x^2 - y^2 - z^2];
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate @ Table[f[x, y, z] == 0, {z, 0, 1, 0.01}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5,5}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Red}]
```

I had thought that the simplest way to parallelize this would be to use `ListContourPlot`, but I don't know how to construct

```
data = Flatten[ParallelTable[...], n]
```

What is the correct and simplest way to do parallelize this?

Comment: something like `data = ParallelTable[
 f[x, y, z], {z, 0, 1, 0.05}, {x, -5, 5, .25}, {y, -5, 5, .25}]; ListContourPlot[data]`?

Comment: Yes, but the run time is long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
ParallelTable[
  ContourPlot[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Red}], {z, 0, 1, 0.01}
  ] // Show
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OK, but the execution time is too long. With a more complicated function, this code saturates the memory.

Comment: @KAMAL The question was how to parallelize. `ContourPlot` is pretty efficient on average.  If it's too slow or uses too much memory, maybe you should look for a particular way to optimize your particular problem. The options `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` affect time, memory and quality.  You can restrict the number of subkernels to avoid using too much memory at once. On the test example, my machine uses 8 (virtual) cores, running about 85-90%, each using less than 200MB, minimal swapping if any; it takes 13 sec.

Comment: OK thank you for your valuable help